# How to open PDF on android using Intent to edit file?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, edit

I'm trying to use Intent on my Android app to open PDF file in another third party app (e.g. adobe reader, etc..) using the code below.

I'm able to successfully open the pdf file and edit its contents but when I exit the pdf app it generates additional copy of the PDF file with the intended changes. It doesn't save the changes on the original file itself. Any ideas why?

I have used the appropriate URI read/write permissions as below:

```
Intent chooserIntent = new Intent();

chooserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
// Also tried action_edit with no luck:  chooserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);

chooserIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, mimeType);
chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
chooserIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Any direction in the right direction is hugely appreciated. I've been stuck on this for some time.
At the moment I'm opening a file called 'Test.pdf' and when I annotate and exit the file, it saves these changes as 'Test1.pdf'. If I opened it again it will generate yet another file called 'Test2.pdf'... I tried adobe reader, ezPDF with same results.

The original PDF is saved in '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Test' folder while the newly generated PDF files are saved in following directory (in case of ezPDF reader): '/storage/emulated/0/ezPDFReader/bookdata/library'

Looking forward to hearing from you,
Many thanks..

Comment: You cannot do anything as you have no control over thar pdf editor app. Choose another editor. Which app do you use?

Comment: I have used both adobe reader and ezPDF apps. Just wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the intent above.. both apps can edit and save the file outside of the intent call. i.e if I browse to the file and then open the file in either adobe or ezPDF, they both can edit and save the original PDF file.

Comment: That is indeed strange behaviour. But with which app are you browsing to a file?

Comment: @blackapps I'm using 'ES File Explorer' to browse and open the PDF file in third party apps like adobe reader. Yes I agree it is strange behaviour and I'm boggled.. Just wondering if you know of any other PDF readers that would do the trick.. Many thanks.

Comment: I think that ES FileExplorer delivers a file path. Please try other explorers that deliver content uri.

Comment: Has anybody had any luck on finding a PDF editor that can save back to the same file after having been opened via Intent.ACTION_EDIT ?

Comment: Are there any news on this topic? We still have the same problem and were not able to find a solution . It seems the we have to save the modified file to an additional copy and ask the user to import it to our app once again and delete the copy. From my point of view, thats a horrible user experience.